# Ghostscript: Font issue during conversion PDF -> PS -> PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

I have to convert fonts inside PDF to curves (original PDF is generated by JasperReport). I found that it can be done using Ghostscript by conversion to PostScript and than back to PDF. I'm using following commands:

Conversion to PostScript:

```
gswin32c.exe -dNoOutputFonts -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=output.ps -f original.pdf
```

Conversion to PDF:

```
gswin32c.exe -dNoOutputFonts -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -sOutputFile=output.pdf -f output.ps
```

Now I have problem inside output PDF with fonts. They are jagged. Any idea how it can be fixed?

Example (Calibri font):
[image: Incorrect font example:]

Comment: First of all, the route PDF -> PS -> PDF is also called refrying PDF files and it should be avoided as a general solution as it can ruin many other things in the PDF file (or at least deteriorate them). Why do you need to do this? And can you provide an example original & converted file?

Answer (score 0):

As David says, don't do this unless you absolutely have to, multiple conversions are a really bad idea. *Any* conversion (as opposed to the sort of simple manipulation performed by some PDF tools, such as extracting or inserting pages) is liable to cause some reduction in fidelity.

That said, the result you see should not happen. However as David also implies, we'd need to see an example file to be able to say more. You should also state the operating system you are using (clearly Windows in this case but it isn't always obvious) and the version of Ghostscript you are using.

If you are using a recent version of Ghostscript (and if you aren't, then you should get the latest) you can use the switch -dNoOutputFonts which will do pretty much what it says. Fonts in the input will be drawn as vector shapes, not fonts, in the output. Be aware that this will increase the file size of the output, possibly quite significantly.

That way you can use a single step, PDF input to PDF output. However please do read (and understand the implications) the Overview section in ghostpdl/doc/VectorDevices.htm in the 9.19 release of Ghostscript.